# Updating a post using Patch

Tags: reactjs, endpoint

How do I use the Patch method to update a Post using a token. I made the post now I have to update it. I have the API endpoint already in index.js. I see that the post I am doing is added however, I need to update them and delete them but I can't seem to get the DELETE or PATCH to work. It keeps saying I have an invalid token.

```
import { useState } from 'react';
import { makePost, updatePost, } from '../API';

export default function Createposts() {
    const [title, setTitle] = useState("")
    const [description, setDescription] = useState("")
    const [price, setPrice] = useState("")
    const [willDeliver, setWillDeliver] = useState("")
    
    const handleSubmit = async (e) => {
        e.preventDefault()
        let token = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("token"))
        const response = await makePost(token, title, description, price, willDeliver)
        const result = await response.json();
        console.log(result);

return (
        <div>
            <h1>Create Posts</h1>
            <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
                <label htmlFor="title">Title</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="title"
                    value={title}
                    onChange={(e) => { setTitle(e.target.value) }} />

                <label htmlFor="description">Description</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="description"
                    value={description}
                    onChange={(e) => { setDescription(e.target.value) }} />

                <label htmlFor="price">Price</label>
                <input
                    type="text"
                    id="price"
                    value={price}
                    onChange={(e) => { setPrice(e.target.value) }} />

                <label htmlFor="willDeliver">WillDeliver</label>
                    <select name="willDeliver" id="willDeliver" onChange={(e) => {   setWillDeliver(e.target.value) }}
                >
                    <option value="false">
                        false
                    </option>

                    <option value="true">
                        true
                    </option>
                </select>
                <button type="submit">Add Posts</button>
                <button type="submit">Update Posts</button>

            </form>
        </div>
    )
}
```

Comment: The actual API request seems to happen in `makePost`, `updatePost`. Could you please share these functions